# Selecting elements of a list based on frequency

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Suppose I have a list as follow:

```
l = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "d", "b"}, {"a", "c", "e"}};
```

Now I am going to flatten it and apply `Counts` to count each element:

```
l // Flatten // Counts

<|"a" -> 4, "b" -> 3, "c" -> 2, "d" -> 1, "e" -> 1|>
```

Now I want to do followings:

1. From the list how can I retain only sublists whose components have frequency more than 1 in the overall list `l`, namely the output should look like this:

   ```
   {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "b"}}
   ```

as all `"a"`, `"b"` and `"c"` have frequency above 1.

2. how can I delete those sublists that contain any components that have frequency 1 from `l`, namely the output should look like:

   ```
   {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "c"}}
   ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
counts = l // Flatten // Counts;
mask = Map[counts[#] != 1 &, l, {2}];
Pick[l, mask]
```

> `{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "c"}}`

And for the other one,

```
mask = Map[counts[#] > 1 &, l, {2}];
Pick[l, And @@@ mask]
```

> `{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "b"}}`

Another way:

```
Map[
 If[counts[#] != 1, #, Nothing] &,
 l, {2}]
```

> `{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "c"}}`

```
If[And @@ (counts[#] > 1 & /@ #), #, Nothing] & /@ l
```

> `{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "b"}}`

Answer (score 4):

Alternatives using `Select` rather than `Pick`:

```
l = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "d", "b"}, {"a", "c", "e"}};
counts = Counts[Flatten@l];
```

1. To obtain the sublists whose elements are repeated in the list:

   ```
   Select[ContainsNone[Keys@Select[# == 1 &]@counts]@l
   (* Out: {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "b"}} *)
   ```
2. To remove those sublists that contain non-repeated elements in the overall list:

   ```
   DeleteCases[Alternatives @@ Keys@Select[# == 1 &]@counts] /@ l
   (* Out: {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "c"}} *)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "d", "b"}, {"a", "c", "e"}};
```

Pre-define `c` for better readability

```
c = a /. Counts @ Flatten @ a
```

{{4, 3, 2}, {4, 3}, {4, 1, 3}, {4, 2, 1}}

**1st question**

Using `AllTrue`

```
Pick[a, AllTrue[GreaterThan @ 1] /@ c]
```

{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "b"}}

**2nd question**

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1) and `Nothing`

```
ReplaceAt[_ :> Nothing, Position[1] @ c] @ a
```

{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "c"}}

Answer (score 1):

Using `Tally` and `AssociationThread` to obtain the frequency of all elements:

```
counts = Merge[AssociationThread @@@ Tally[Flatten@#], Identity[#[[1]]] &] &@l;
```

**1st question**

Using `Pick` and `FreeQ`:

```
Pick[#, FreeQ[#, 1] & /@ (# /. counts)] &@l

(*{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "b"}}*)
```

**2nd question**

Using `Select` and `DeleteElements`:

```
DeleteElements[#, Keys[Select[counts, # == 1 &]]] & /@ l

(*{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "c"}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

l = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "d", "b"}, {"a", "c", "e"}};
items = Union@Flatten@l (* find unique items *)

(*{"a","b","c","d","e"}*)

lens = Position[l, #] & /@ items // Map[Length]  (* find tallies *)

(*{4,3,2,1,1}*)

del = Pick[items, lens, 1]  (* identify items to be deleted *)


(*{"d","e"}*)
```

or do so more directly:

```
(* Tally@Flatten@l /. {a_, Except[1]} :> Nothing // Map[First] *)
```

**First question**

```
DeleteCases[l, _?(ContainsAny[del])]
```

**Secondquestion**

```
DeleteCases[l, Alternatives @@ del, {2}]
```

---

> {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "b"}}

> {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "c"}}